# Can I use same admob id for same iphone and android application?

Tags: android, ios

I am new to android. I have to make same app in both iphone and android. Can I use same google admob id for android and ios devices? Please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do so.

You need to make different apps in admob deashboard for android and ios.

This will lead to different publisher ids.

Can you explain the situation a bit further.